# Can a single company enroll in both the Apple Developer Program and the Apple Developer Enterprise Program?

Tags: ios, developer-program, enterprise

As per [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/) website, an organisation can enroll in **Apple Developer Program** and **Apple Developer Enterprise Program**.

Is it possible for a company to be enrolled in both at the same time? For instance, if the company has apps that are meant for internal distribution only, but also has other apps which are targeted at customers and are distributed via the App Store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, It is possible from a single company to be enrolled in both the **Apple Developer** (Organisation) and the **Apple Developer Enterprise** program.

Kindly note that you will require a separate Apple ID to enroll in Apple Developer Enterprise Program. Quoting from the [Enrollment Support Page](https://developer.apple.com/support/enrollment/):

> ### Enrolling in Multiple Programs
>
> The Apple Developer Enterprise Program and the iOS Developer University Program each require a unique Apple ID than that used for any other membership. You’ll need to set up a new Apple ID and enroll separately. If you currently have an iTunes Connect account to sell another media type (books, music, TV content, or movies), you cannot use the Apple ID associated with that iTunes Connect account to enroll in any other programs. You’ll need to set up a new Apple ID for all other memberships.

**Disclaimer**: I have worked with a company as a developer which has enrolled in both the programs. I was **not** the legal entity responsible for managing the accounts. I recommended you go through the [Membership Support](https://developer.apple.com/support/membership/) documents before proceeding.

Comment: This support page makes no mention of being in the regular Developer Program as an organization and being in the Enterprise Developer Program at the same time. It only mentions Enterprise and University programs.  It kinda suggests it might be possible, by saying you need "a new Apple ID for all other memberships", but it doesn't spell it out.

Comment: I know for sure that you'll need a separate Apple ID for both. Also, as I have mentioned in the answer, it is definitely possible for an organisation to to enrolled in both the programs simultaneously. However, also note the disclaimer.

Comment: I have a company that is enrolled as both Apple Developer (for selling paid apps on the App Store) as well as Apple Developer Enterprise (for offering internal apps to employees via own infrastructure). I'm the admin and legal role, and can thus say that this is fully possible. It does however, as mentioned, require that you have two Apple-IDs - a very small requirement.